# Implementing react hooks useState in material-ui Tab container not working

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui, react-hooks

I am trying to implement react-hooks useState in material-ui/tabs component. I am able to do it with function handleChange, but I am trying to learn to implement hooks. useState is working for input field but not for material-ui tabs onChange function. Following is my code:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

<Tabs
   value={value}
   onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
   variant="scrollable"
   scrollButtons="on"
   indicatorColor="primary"
   textColor="primary"
 >
     <Tab label="All" />
         {subjects.map((subject) => (
             <Tab label={subject.subjectName} />
      ))}
 </Tabs>
```

I tried console log with useEffect, and it returns `undefined` onChange

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main issue I see is that

```
onChange={(event) => setValue(event.target.value)}
```

should instead be:

```
onChange={(event, newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
```

The `event` in this case is just a click event and the `target` will be the particular DOM element clicked on which could be any one of several elements (e.g. span, button) that make up the `Tab`. Unlike with `input` elements, none of the DOM elements in the `Tab` have a `value` property, so Material-UI passes the value as a separate argument to the `onChange` function.

Here is the relevant code from the `Tab` component:

```
  handleChange = event => {
    const { onChange, value, onClick } = this.props;

    if (onChange) {
      onChange(event, value);
    }

    if (onClick) {
      onClick(event);
    }
  };
```

You'll find the `onChange` signature documented in the documentation for the `Tabs` props: https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/#props

> onChange `func` Callback fired when the value changes. Signature: `function(event: object, value: number) => void`

Here's a working example based on your code:

[image: Edit Tabs useState]

Comment: Thankyou for your help! I still don't get why we need newValue in this one but not in the input field. Can you clear this out for me?

Comment: @SujanJoshi I've added some additional information to my answer.